# TypeError grid search

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, pca, grid-search

I used to create loop for finding the best parameters for my model which increased my errors in coding so I decided to use `GridSearchCV`. 
I am trying to find out the best parameters for PCA for my model (the only parameter I want to grid search on). 
 
In this model, after normalization I want to combine the original features with the PCA reduced features and then apply the linear SVM. 
Then I save the whole model to predict my input on. 
I have an error in the line where I try to fit the data so I can use `best_estimator_` and `best_params_` functions. 
The error says: `TypeError: The score function should be a callable, all (<type 'str'>) was passed.` I did not use any parameters for which I might need to give string in `GridSearchCV`so not sure why I have this error 
I also want to know if the line `print("shape after model",X.shape)` before saving my model, should should print `(150, 7) and (150, 5)` both based on all possible parameter?

```html
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from numpy import array

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

print(X.shape) #prints (150, 4)
print (y)

#cretae models and piplline them
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("pca", PCA()), ("univ_select", SelectKBest(k='all'))])
svm = SVC(kernel="linear")

pipeline = Pipeline([("scale", StandardScaler()),("features", combined_features), ("svm", svm)])

# Do grid search over n_components:
param_grid = dict(features__pca__n_components=[1,3])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, verbose=10)
grid_search.fit(X, y)
print("best parameters", grid_search.best_params_)

print("shape after model",X.shape) #should this print (150, 7) or (150, 5) based on best parameter?

#save the model
joblib.dump(grid_search.best_estimator_, 'model.pkl', compress = 1)

#new data to predict
Input=[ 2.9 , 4.  ,1.2  ,0.2]
Input= array(Input)

#use the saved model to predict the new data
modeltrain="model.pkl"
modeltrain_saved = joblib.load(modeltrain) 
model_predictions = modeltrain_saved.predict(Input.reshape(1, -1))
print(model_predictions)
```

I updated the code based on the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supplying `'all'` as a param in SelectKBest. But according to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest), if you want to pass 'all', you need to specify it as:

```
SelectKBest(k='all')
```

The reason is that its a keyword argument, it should be specified with the keyword. Because the first argument to SelectKBest is a positional argument for the scoring function. So when you do not specify the `param`, 'all' is considered an input for the function and hence the error.

Update:

Now about the shape, the original `X` will not be changed. So it will print `(150,4)`. The data will be changed on the fly and on my pc the `best_param_` is `n_components=1`, so final shape that goes to svm is `(150, 5)`, 1 from PCA and 4 from SelectKBest.

Comment: @Vivek_Kumar Also, is "features__pca__n_components" a keyword that is recognized by GridSearchCV as a parameter for PCA. If not how it wouldn't miss recognize it for another param such as gamma of SVM which I did not define in param_grid? thanks

Comment: @april Yes `"features__pca__n_components"` is a keyword for the pipeline object. GridSearch just sends the keywords to pipeline. And then pipeline will handle the assignment, based on names used when making the pipeline.

Comment: @Vivek_Kumar: I have seen one question you answered in another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160206/does-gridsearchcv-perform-cross-validation) but I couldn't reply, it's kind of related to what I posted here. If I split my data into 75% for training data and 25% for test and perform grid_search over training data and after obtaining the best parameters I want to compute the accuracy of my model on the test data. Is it important if for the evaluation of my model on test data that I use the same number of cross validations as I used for grid search over training data?

Comment: @april No, you just call `predict()` or `score()` on test data for evaluation. You dont cross-validate on test data. If so, what will you do in each fold?

Comment: @Vivek_Kumar: got it thanks, still I have a question about the necessity of having separate unseen data as our test data to evaluate if our final model is bias or not.  grid_result.cv_results_ also calculates the mean_test_score and mean_train_score (for all possible parameters not only the best) so considering in each iteration i-th fold is unseen, we still should be able to say from the difference between mean-test and mean-train scores that our model is bias or not.