# GridSearchCV freezing with linear svm

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, grid-search

I have problem with GridSearchCV freezing (CPU is active but program in not advancing) with linear svm (but with rbf svm it works fine). 

Depending on the random_state that I use for splitting my data, I have this freezing in different splits points of cv for different PCA components? 

The features of one sample looks like the following(it is about 39 features)

```
[1 117 137 2 80 16 2 39 228 88 5 6 0 10 13 6 22 23 1 227 246 7 1.656934307 0 5 0.434195726 0.010123735 0.55568054 5 275 119.48398 0.9359527 0.80484825 3.1272728 98 334 526 0.13454546 0.10181818]
```

Another sample's features:

```
[23149 4 31839 9 219 117 23 5 31897 12389 108 2 0 33 23 0 0 18 0 0 0 23149 0 0 74 0.996405221 0.003549844 4.49347E-05 74 5144 6.4480677 0.286384 0.9947901 3.833787 20 5135 14586 0.0060264384 0.011664075]
```

If I delete the last 10 feature I don't have this problem ( The 10 new features that I added before my code worked fine). I did not check other combinations of the 10 last new features to check if a specific feature is causing this problem.
Also I use `StandardScaler` to scale the features but still facing this issue. I have less of this problem if I use `MinMaxScaler` scaler (but read soewhere it is not good for svm).
I also put `n_jobs` to different numbers and it only could advance by little but freezes again.
What do you suggest? 
I followed part of this code to write my code:
[TypeError grid seach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101117/typeerror-grid-seach)

Comment: Have you looked at ram consumption? maybe it's starting swapping

Comment: I checked it but I see no problem there.

Comment: can you add some data and the code? I want to reproduce this.